# Brightness Control in ubuntu 13.04-64bit not working in Toshiba T110

Tags: 64-bit, display, brightness, 13.04

I'm new to this forum and thought I'd try it out. So, much like every edition since about 11.10 brightness control doesn't work "out-of-the-box". I have a Toshiba Satellite T110-12P and although I've managed to solve the problem in earlier editions, this time I cannot. I have tried adding the "acpi_backlight=vendor" kernel parameter but unlike other times, it did not solve the problem. I found a somewhat complicated solution by running some commands but I'd like to find a more comfortable one. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Could you share the commands you used?

Comment: Sure, I used:
"lspci | grep -i vga" to check for the BusID and "sudo setpci -s 00:02.0 F4.B=90" to adjust the brightness. Replacing "90" with my desired brightness level.

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution that worked on my Acer Aspire V3-531G laptop with Ubuntu 13.04-64 bit. This solution does not depend on the hardware, hence I dare to recommend it to you:

1. As root, open the `/etc/default/grub` file in your favourite text editor.
2. Change the line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi=Linux"`
3. Save the file
4. As root, run `update-grub`
5. Reboot
6. Enjoy! :-)

Source: http://en.kioskea.net/faq/12062-adjust-the-brightness-in-ubuntu-10-10

Hope, this helps!

Comment: Already tried it, and all variantes of kernel boot options. None worked, unfortunately...

Answer (score 0):

I have the same thing on one of my Toshiba-Satellite Laptops (the other one works fine). Brightness is always set to minimum after reboot.
I couldn't find a real solution, so I installed a little brightness-indicator, which shows a button in the panel. After startup I can change brightness without the need to open system settings.

"Installing the applet in Ubuntu 11.10 through 13.04 is as easy as running the following commands in a Terminal:

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:indicator-brightness/ppa

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install indicator-brightness

If a PPA is a bit too much for you, you can grab a .Deb installer from the project launchpad page"

https://launchpad.net/~indicator-brightness/+archive/ppa/+packages

You can find the details of the indicator at:
http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/04/brightness-control-ubuntu

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: The thing is, I already tried installing said brightness indicator but it didn't work, the reason being that I can't ajust brightness through system settings. I change the setting but the brightness stays the same...